# Java proxy not showing anything: client <--> server

Tags: java, proxy

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class proxy {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
      String host = "gamea.clashofclans.com";
      int remoteport = 9339;
      ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(0);
      int localport = ss.getLocalPort();
      ss.setReuseAddress(true);
      // Print a start-up message
      System.out.println("Starting proxy for " + host + ":" + remoteport
          + " on port " + localport);
      // And start running the server
      runServer(host, remoteport, localport,ss); // never returns
      System.out.println("Started proxy!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * runs a single-threaded proxy server on
   * the specified local port. It never returns.
   */
  public static void runServer(String host, int remoteport, int localport, ServerSocket ss)
      throws IOException {
    // Create a ServerSocket to listen for connections with
    System.out.println("Connected to Client!");

    final byte[] request = new byte[2048];
    byte[] reply = new byte[4096];

    while (true) {
      Socket client = null, server = null;
      try {
        // Wait for a connection on the local port
        client = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Client Accepted!");

        final InputStream streamFromClient = client.getInputStream();
        final OutputStream streamToClient = client.getOutputStream();

        // Make a connection to the real server.
        // If we cannot connect to the server, send an error to the
        // client, disconnect, and continue waiting for connections.
        try {
          server = new Socket(host, remoteport);
          System.out.println("Client connected to server.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(streamToClient);
          out.print("Proxy server cannot connect to " + host + ":"
              + remoteport + ":\n" + e + "\n");
          out.flush();
          client.close();
          System.out.println("Client disconnected");
          continue;
        }

        // Get server streams.
        final InputStream streamFromServer = server.getInputStream();
        final OutputStream streamToServer = server.getOutputStream();

        // a thread to read the client's requests and pass them
        // to the server. A separate thread for asynchronous.
        Thread t = new Thread() {
          public void run() {
            int bytesRead;
            try {
              while ((bytesRead = streamFromClient.read(request)) != -1) {
                streamToServer.write(request, 0, bytesRead);
                streamToServer.flush();
              }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            // the client closed the connection to us, so close our
            // connection to the server.
            try {
              streamToServer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
          }
        };

        // Start the client-to-server request thread running
        t.start();

        // Read the server's responses
        // and pass them back to the client.
        int bytesRead;
        try {
          while ((bytesRead = streamFromServer.read(reply)) != -1) {
            streamToClient.write(reply, 0, bytesRead);
            streamToClient.flush();
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        // The server closed its connection to us, so we close our
        // connection to our client.
        streamToClient.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      } finally {
        try {
          if (server != null)
            server.close();
          if (client != null)
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run it I get to the message "Connected to client" (line 40) but after that nothing is happening in the window. I don't get the "Client has connected to the server message" so I assume the problem is somewhere around there?

Why is this happening? Does anyone know a fix?

I'm very new to java so please don't be harsh on me.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Connected to Client!" message is misleading. At that point, you are starting your server and clients will soon be able to connect, but no clients have connected yet. Your program is waiting for

```
    client = ss.accept();
```

to return. [ServerSocket.accept](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) waits for a connection to be made across the port. You need another thread, program, or computer to connect to this port to begin hosting them as a client. Make sure that this other thread, program, or computer is properly configured to connect to your open port. You likely need to either set ServerSocket to use a fixed port, or to determine what port it has opened a socket on and tell your other program what port to use.

Comment: I have a game on bluestacks that usesport 9339. Still won't work.

Comment: @Shiv `9339` is the port on `gamea.clashofclans.com` which you are connecting to; your client needs to connect to the port `localport`, which could change each time you run this program.

Comment: @Shiv Depends on your client. If it always connects to port 9339, simply set your localport to always be 9339: `ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9339);`